# Holding retry count in database Spring Retry

Tags: spring-retry, retry-logic

Is it possible to store retry count in database with Spring Retry in case application crashes? Is there there any built-in configuration for that? After restarting application remaining retries need to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not built in, but you could implement a custom `RetryContextCache` and inject it into the `RetryTemplate`.

If you are using stateful retry, you would also need a custom `RetryState`.

You would need logic in your application to call the operation after the restart; spring-retry can not magically continue the retries automatically.